# Show that if $p$ is a prime and $p \in (n, 2n]$, then $p \mid {2n \choose n}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, divisibility

I'm having a problem understanding the answer to this question below.
The step I don't get is underlined in red. I understand everything else just the red underline I am stuck on. Sorry I am a beginner so 
probably it is something very simple but I can't see it .

Question :
[image: Question :]

Answer :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Claim $1$**: If $a \mid c$, $b \mid c$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then $ab \mid c$.

Now note that every prime $p$ between $n$ and $2n$ divides $\dbinom{2n}n$. From Claim $1$, it follows that $\prod_{n < p < 2n}p$ divides $\dbinom{2n}n$.

Comment: Crystal clear , Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

Call $P_n= \{ p \mbox{ prime} : n < p \le 2n\}$. You just showed that for all $p \in P_n$ you have that $p$ divides $\binom{2n}{n}$. So in the prime factorization of $\binom{2n}{n}$ all such primes appear.

In particular $\prod_{p \in P_n} p$ divides $\binom{2n}{n}$, hence it is smaller.

Comment: Very insightful , thank you .