# Show that $2n\choose n$ divisible by primes $p,$ such that $n<p<2n$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients, divisibility

Suppose on the contrary that $2n \choose n$ is not divisible by $p\in (n,2n)$. There exis $k$ and $0\ne r\lt p$ such that

$(2n)\cdots (n+1)=kp \,n!+r \, n!$. The second term on RHS is not divisible by $p$ as $p>n$. I'm not sure how to conclude from here that $r=0$. Any hints on this are much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: A few other related posts: [Show that if $p$ is a prime satisfying $n<p<2n$ then $\binom{2n}{n}\equiv 0 \pmod p$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2103981), [Prove that $\binom{2n}{n} > \prod_{p > n}^{p<2n}{p}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1876193) or [Show that if $p$ is a prime and $p \in (n, 2n]$, then $p \mid {2n \choose n}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1291594)

Comment: Not helpful for this quesrion, but an amusing characterization of all primes $p$ such that $p\mid\binom{2n}n$ is they are the primes $p$ such that, when $n$ is written is base $p,$ there is some digit that is at least $\frac p2.$